# How to use Cesiumjs without bingmap api key

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis, cesium

Can I use cesiumjs without bingmap api key. I need to create a viewer which should use my own wms layer and osm. Further i want to use it as a platform for geospatial analysis on my spatial data. As i know cesiumjs is a opensource tool but why it needs bingmap api key.

Answer (score 2):

Cesium uses the Bing key for two purposes, so to get it to stop warning about the key you have to turn both of these off:

1. The default imagery layer is Bing Maps.
2. The Geocoder widget uses Bing API for geocoding.

The first one is obvious, and you already have a replacement lined up.  But the second one is the gotcha, most people overlook it.  You can construct the Cesium viewer with `geocoder: false` in the options object to turn it off.  Once you've done both of these things, the Bing key will no longer be in use and the warning message will disappear.